# Convert dataframe into named vectors based on column names

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
```

I want to convert it to three named vectors:

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
```

How can I do this programmatically? `tidyverse` solutions especially appreciated.

Comment: (1) It this really your data frame (since your code creates a - imho - really broken `df`)? (2) If your actual data.frame is `data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)` I don't think you really want to convert it into three vectors, since you basically have them already (`df[["a"]]` for example).

Comment: You're right that the data frame was incorrect, I have fixed it. But `df[["a"]]` doesn't get me what I want, which is to achieve the specified outcomes programmatically (i.e., without typing a command for each column).

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to do programmatically? I'm still convinced you don't need a vector named `a` and can go with `df["a"]` or in a `tidyverse` way with a curly-curly or bang-bang construct.

Comment: I want some named vectors of length 1 to hold values that I can use in functions (e.g., `rnorm(10,0,a)`.

Comment: In this example `rnorm(10,0,df[["a"]])` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (though @MartinGal gives a better method). We can convert each column to a list, then `flatten` to just have a named vector, then can save to the global environment.

```
library(tidyverse)

list2env(flatten(apply(df, 2, function(x) as.list(x))), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution (you should follow @MartinGal's approach though):

```r
list2env(lapply(df, \(x) `<-`(names(x), x)),.GlobalEnv)

a
#> [1] 1
b
#> [1] 2
c
#> [1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`df[,'a']` also works

Refer [extract operator](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Extract)

Comment: `df[,'a']` doesn't get me what I want, which is to achieve the specified outcomes programmatically (i.e., without typing a command for each column).